# how to "white label" name servers on google cloud DNS?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

It is possible to use [google cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/what-is-cloud-dns) and white label the nameservers so that instead of using:

```
ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com.
```

I could use something like:

```
ns1.mydomain.com
ns2.mydomain.com
ns3.mydomain.com
ns4.mydomain.com
```

Or how safe/easy is to use Amazon approach for this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html.

What about creating an `A` record similar to the  IP's of `ns-cloud-*` to custom domain, something like:

```
ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com  IN A 216.239.32.106
```

to

```
ns1.mydomain.com IN A 216.239.32.106
```

any ideas?

Comment: Hey @nbari, did you figure it out eventually?

Comment: @21st, it works like in the accepted answer, problem is that if IP changes you need to update records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need glue records for the IP addresses of your nsX.mydomain.com nameservers (216.239.32.106 etc). This resolves the catch-22 of a client trying to resolve a host under your domain finding it needs to resolve the DNS name of your nameserver in order to contact it. Your registrar should be able to help you with this.